# How to optimise this slow MySQL query - late row lookups?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm converting a site over to use XenForo as forum software, however this site has millions of thread rows in the MySQL table. If I try to browse a paginated listing of threads, it slows to a crawl the further I go. Once I'm at page 10,000 it takes almost 30s.

My aim is to improve the query below, perhaps by using late row lookups so that I can make this query run faster:

```
SELECT thread.*
    ,
    user.*, IF(user.username IS NULL, thread.username, user.username) AS username,
    NULL AS thread_read_date,
    0 AS thread_is_watched,
    0 AS user_post_count
FROM xf_thread AS thread

    LEFT JOIN xf_user AS user ON
        (user.user_id = thread.user_id)
WHERE (thread.node_id = 152) AND (thread.sticky = 0) AND (thread.discussion_state IN ('visible'))
ORDER BY thread.last_post_date DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 238340

Run Time: 4.383607

Select Type    Table    Type    Possible Keys    Key    Key Len    Ref    Rows    Extra      
SIMPLE    thread    ref    node_id_last_post_date,node_id_sticky_state_last_post    node_id_last_post_date    4    const    552480    Using where      
SIMPLE    user    eq_ref    PRIMARY    PRIMARY    4    sitename.thread.user_id    1
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `xf_thread` (
  `thread_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `node_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `reply_count` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `view_count` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `post_date` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sticky` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `discussion_state` ENUM('visible','moderated','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'visible',
  `discussion_open` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `discussion_type` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `first_post_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `first_post_likes` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_post_date` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `last_post_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `last_post_user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `last_post_username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `prefix_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sonnb_xengallery_import` TINYINT(3) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`thread_id`),
  KEY `node_id_last_post_date` (`node_id`,`last_post_date`),
  KEY `node_id_sticky_state_last_post` (`node_id`,`sticky`,`discussion_state`,`last_post_date`),
  KEY `last_post_date` (`last_post_date`),
  KEY `post_date` (`post_date`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=2977 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Can anyone help me improve the speed of this query? I'm a real MySQL novice, but I am running the same dataset on other forum software and it is much faster - so I'm sure there is a way somehow. This table is INNODB and I'd consider the server well optimised.

Comment: First reason should be thread.discussion_state IN ('visible'). Why there is a need of IN if only one value need to match. Replace it with thread.discussion_state='visible'

Comment: What is the index on the tables xf_user & xf_thread. Please post the schema.

Comment: I've edited the post to add the schema.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

The concept being, query just the index column with your required paging/ordering, then join this list to the other columns you want from the table

Answer (score 0):

Your User table is already index by user ID... good.

For your thread table, I would have a compound index on it with the key

( note_id, sticky, discussion_state, last_post_date )

This way, the index is optimized on all parts in the WHERE clause... AND since it has the last_post_date too, that can be utilized by the ORDER BY clause.  Order By clauses are notorious for killing query performance.